# How do I horizontally align 2 divs inside a parent div

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

I have this portion of a box:

[image]

I want the text to horizontally align with the surrounding div I put it inside. Right now my code is like so:

```
.cssAward {
   width: 299px;
   height: 54px;
   margin: auto;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   display: flex;
}

.cssImageBox {
   float: left;
   width: 60px;
   height: 54px;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}

.cssBoxText {
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #5e5e5e;
   font-family: inherit;
   font-weight: 300;
   margin-left: 15px;
   height: 54px;
   width: 224px;
}
```

And the HTML for that section is:

```
 <div class="cssAward">
     <div class="cssImageBox">
         <img class="cssBadge" src="images/celeb5star.png"/>
     </div>
     <div class="cssBoxText">
       Multi-year top sales agent
     </div>
 </div>
```

What can I do to my code to make the text align horizontally with the Badges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the cssBoxText a flex too and then apply some flex properties you should be able to do this without too many problems:

```
.cssBoxText {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

Alternatively if you add:

```
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
```

To .cssAward that should do it too.

Flex makes solving layout issues quite easy. You need to commit to using it though. If you start mixing flexbox with floats and vertical-align, text-align etc you may get unexpected results.

It's worth reading up on flexbox - it's really powerful.

Comment: A couple of good resources for getting to grips with flexbox:

http://flexboxfroggy.com/

https://ohansemmanuel.github.io/uf_download.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the line height?

```
  .cssBoxText {
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, line-height works for labels that are 1 sentence, but the ones that are 2 become distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Like swervo said but if you want to keep your 15px margin. Remove the `justify-content: center;` and keep your `margin-left: 15px;`.

```
 .cssBoxText {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        flex-basis: auto;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
```